# Sources about device emulation in QEMU

Tags: qemu, qemu-device

Currently im wrinting a summary doc about how does QEMU work, mainly i explain concepts and only explain the most important features. Currently i have explained how CPU emulation is made with TCG, as its the default acelerator in QEMU, but im having some trouble finding documentation for my next section: how does device emulation work. Here i would like to explain how diferent devices are emulated, not any in particular, just how the emulation is made and whats the structure of those devices. Im i missundersanding something? Do you know any source about device emulation to understand the concept better? The next section im planning is QEMU memory managment.